# Relative path to physical path

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io, readfile

`<rant>`
firstly, I've searched a lot and every single question / blog asks/tells about how to convert physical path to relative, never the other way around. If I've missed that question here, I am sorry.
`<rant />`

So, I have a directory structure very similar to this:

```
Root
|....Components
|....Classes
|....Utils
     |....FileUtils
          |....Assets //this is a folder
          |....FileAccess.cs
```

So, in my `FileAccess.cs` I just want to read the content of a text file and display it on a page.
in my `webpage.aspx.cs` I am calling the `getFileContent()` which is in utils.

so the relative path from FileAccess.cs is `Assets\spec.txt`

So, how on earth can I access that with code?

this is what I am trying / tried:

```
  //function getFileContent() content..
private const string QuestionnairePath = @"Assets\";
return Server.MapPath(QuestionnairePath + "spec.html");
```

it ALWAYS throws file not found exception and upon debugging it's not selecting the right folder.
I have even tried this:

```
private const string QuestionnairePath = @"~Utils\FileUtils\Assets\";
```

that doesn't work either.

This must be very easy. Just can't figure it out, for the life of me. I hate being a newbie sometimes.

Help please,
Thanks.

ps: Ideally, I would just want to use relative path: `Assets\` - wonder if that is possible.

Comment: Did you tried @"~\Utils\FileUtils\Assets\" ?

Comment: @sll - I did, but it did not work for relative path...